# restful WCF service authentication

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, authentication, pki

I have an application which exposes service which is consumed by the web application via Jquery POST and other applications (IPad, Android, etc). I have to create an authentication system which is highly safe but still fast enough.

I thought of making a token which will be passed to the application on login and which will be used for a specific amount of time (say 30 mins) post which it should refresh itself and not expire the session. So I thought of making a token being sent to service and which will generate token. It will accept

1. UserId
2. Password (both encrypted with public key)
3. AppId

The server will decrypt the request by the private key and generate a token which will be valid for a specific time. Now since this would highly depend on the private key (which will be same and thus someone from within system can leak it and misuse it) so i want the private key to be refreshed after a specific time (say 2 hrs).

Question -

1. How do refresh Private key and ensure that the currently issues tokens will not be rejected.
2. Is there a better way of doing it

Comment: Re #1, you can save the old key until the last session that is using it has expired - meaning the key would be around for a max of 4 hours.

Comment: What do you mean by "Now since this would highly depend on the private key (which will be same and thus someone from within system can leak it and misuse it)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Is there a better way of doing it?**

Yes there is, It's called SSL/HTTPS.  If you are already using HTTPS then there is no need for any of this crypto-magic.  If you are not using HTTPS you are already insecure by design and nothing you come up with will fix that short of re-inventing SSL.

**So what should you do if the transport is secure (HTTPS)**

1. Client makes a request for authentication sending username + password in plain-text.
2. Server verifies the username + password pair against the (hopefully) hashed password stored with the account.
3. Server responds with a token (encrypted account id, expiration, etc) using a static AES key.
4. Client uses the token for all authenticated requests.

Easy.

**One thing you could do...**

To prevent loss of credentials used on non-secure devices you should take a page from Google and others.  Rather than having users entering their website passwords, make them visit and log in to your web server.  From there they click a 'generate access token for device'.  A unique data string (20 or more characters) is generated and recorded with their account.  This 'alternate password' can then be revoked by the user from your website.

**How can I make this more secure?**

You really can't do much better, here is why...

Assume an attacker gains access to your private key.  The attacker can then replace your server or play man-in-the-middle while stealing usernames and passwords.

To attempt to prevent this you contrive some PKI exchange to send the password encrypted by a public key the server gave you.  I as a man-in-the-middle can simply give you my own public key and access the username and password and then if I choose, forward it to the real server.

*--or--*

To attempt to prevent this you use some salt + password hash that will be sent to the server in place of the password in clear text.  I as a man-in-the-middle can simply give you a fixed value for the salt and then pre-compute a complete rainbow table for that salt value.  Now I again have everyone's password (well most) in clear text.

*--or--*

To attempt to prevent this you use PKI to establish some secret session key and then sign and encrypt every communication.  Well, gee... that sounds familiar... see [SSL on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).  Realize that the *ONLY* thing that makes SSL secure is the protection of it's private keys.  Once a private key is lost, all security and trust is lost.

**Final notes:**

Without being able to protect some encryption key you cannot build a secure communication.

You should also be aware that thousands of man hours have been spent on software implementations of SSL (like OpenSSL) and they constantly find vulnerabilities in their implementations.  Your hope of implementing this yourself, and doing it as secure as IIS or OpenSSL, is almost NIL.  That is not a Digg on you, that is just reality, I couldn't do it either I only know enough to not even try.

Lastly, my final advice is about your statement: "someone from within system can leak it and misuse it".  This is your real problem.  Fix that and all else will be much easier.  Securing a server environment should be your first priority.  Your second priority should be minimizing the impact to your customers once you fail to do the first.

**Some helpful links:**

- [How to generate password using a specific set of characters.](http://csharptest.net/1074/how-to-generate-password-using-a-specific-set-of-characters/)
- [Another example of how to store a salted password hash.](http://csharptest.net/470/another-example-of-how-to-store-a-salted-password-hash/)